# System.Security.AccessControl denying right for DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles does not work

Tags: c#, security, powershell, acl

I trying to deny specified permissions from a user using System.Security.AccessControl. 
I have issues with denying right to DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles or Delete.

My code seems to work for other members of FileSystemRights Enumeration, just these ones do not have any effect. Below the example of my code:

```
accessRule= new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("myUser",System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles,System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.None,System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags.None,System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny);

dSecurity= System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(startDir);
driveSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(startDir,dSecurity);
```

This would work if I change FileSystemRights to something else e.g. CreateDirectories, but neither DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles nor Delete do. I was having the same problem with PowerShell script. Could you advise what is the reason? Many thanks

Comment: Probably a copypaste typo: `driveSecurity` is not `dSecurity`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry for the copy-paste error, but I only made it  here. The code I have works for everything else. Also I noticed later that DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFile also works so that I can see the rule applied, only you still can delete subdirectories.  Let's say it is like that: I am logged in as an user of with full control right. With this code I can effectively deny the other rights. E.g. if I deny Write he cannot write, but with this one though the rule is applied  deleting Subdirectories And Files is still possible. Do you have any advise why that is and how to overcome that?